# Enviar relatório pelo node-jasper

Tags: node.js, jasper-reports

Estou tentando enviar relatórios através de requisições pelo node.js. Para isso estou usando o node-jasper, mas quando faço a requisição da minha api aparece o erro na imagem: [requisição da api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI9va.png)

Já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei o que causa este erro.. O relatorio foi criado no Jaspersoft Studio-6.19.1, minha versão de java é a 11 e o node é a versão 16.14.0. Já testei usar a lib jasperreports-6.19.1 e jasperreports-6.2.0 e ambas resultaram no mesmo erro.

Aqui está a conexão com o banco e o jasper:

```js
jasper = require('node-jasper')(
  {
   // path: '../lib/jasperreports-6.2.0',//19.1 // 'lib/jasperreports-6.2.0'
     path: '../lib/jasperreports-6.19.1',
    reports: {
      hw: {
        jasper: '../reports/aa.jasper'
        //jasper: 'testando.jasper'
        // jrxml: 'testando.jrxml'
        //jrxml: '../reports/testando.jrxml'
      }
    }
    ,
    drivers: {
      jdbc: {
        path: '../driver/jaybird-full-4.0.9.java11.jar',
        class: 'org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver',
        type: 'jdbc'
      }
    }
    ,
    conns: {
      dbserver1: {
        // host: 'localhost/xe',
        // port: 1521,
        jdbc: 'jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/C:\\BD\\BD_PROD.FDB',
        // dbname: 'xe',
        user: 'sysdba',
        pass: 'managerr'
        // driver: 'jdbc'
      }
    },
    defaultConn: 'dbserver1'
  }
);

module.exports = jasper;
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu faço dessa forma para conectar no postgress

export function initJasper() {
Jasper = require('node-jasper')({
path: '../lib/jasperreports-6.20.0',
reports: JASPER_REPORTS(),
drivers: {
pg: {
path: '../lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jre7.jar',
class: 'org.postgresql.Driver',
type: 'postgresql'
}
},
conns: {
dbserver1: {
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
port: process.env.DB_PORT,
dbname: process.env.DB_NAME,
user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
pass: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
driver: 'pg'
}
},
defaultConn: 'dbserver1'
});
}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).